# Question related to domain and range of function

Tags: functions

There was this question to find the domain and range of of the function f defined by $f(x)=(|x|-x)/2x$

So we can easily see that the domain of the function is = $\mathbb R-\{0\}$,
since denominator cant be $0$, therefore, range of the given function will be:

if $X>0$:

$$y=\frac{|x|-x}{2x}\\
y=\frac{x-x}{2x}
y=\frac{0}{2x}\\
y=0
$$
and if $x<0$:

$$y=\frac{|-x|-x}{2x}\\
y=\frac{-(-x)-x}{2x}\\
y=\frac{x-x}{2x}\\
y=0$$

therefore the range of the given function will be:{0}

But in my book the range = {0,-1}

Can anyone explain me how -1 is an element of range?

Comment: If $x$ is negative, then $|x|=-x.$ So, you should have $y=\frac{-x-x}{2x}=-1$ in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an issue in the case for $x<0$: $|x|=-x$. Then $$y=\frac{|x|-x}{2x}=\frac{-x-x}{2x}=-1$$

Comment: But if x<0 then x=-x therefore |-x|=-(-x) =x

Comment: @MadDawg Your mistake is that it's not the case that $x=-x$. That's almost never the case. The truth is that if $x<0$ then $|x|=-x$.

Comment: Or better written as $x=-|x|$. $x=-x$ is true only if $x=0$

Comment: Oh yes got it